# Create an object constructor that contains nested arrays and objects populated from form input

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, constructor

I am a full beginner. But I am trying to understand this problem up to its core.

**I have this assignment:**

Create a functional pizza order application using HTML, JavaScript, AJAX, and JSON.

- Include fields for name, address, and phone number.
- Allow for multiple toppings per pizza, with at least six toppings
  to choose from.
- Allow for multiple pizzas per order.
- Include support for at least three pizza sizes, with different
  prices for toppings based on pizza size.
- Dynamically display order information and price total as pizzas
  and toppings are added.
- Include 10% sales tax. Include a    comments section for special
  notes and/or delivery instructions.
- Your  solution will include an Order object, which contains a
  Customer  object, an array of Pizza objects, and a nested array of
  toppings for each pizza.
- Use AJAX and JSON to submit order information.

For full credit, you must use separate subroutines/functions/methods to implement each type of processing and include error handling for missing or invalid data.

**My dilemma** is how to create the Order object constructor. Or the pizza object constructor instead. I guess the pizza object constructor since the order is submitted once, but the pizza instances are being added to the order each time the "Add Pizza" is clicked. This is a schematic visualization of my understanding:

```js
function Order(address, phone,fullName,toppings,size,price ){
    customerObject = {fullName,address,phone},      //comes from input fields
    PizzaArray = ['pizza[1]','pizza[2]','pizza[3]','pizza[4]',...,'pizza[n]']   //an instance of pizza object generates each time the "Add Pizza" button is clicked
    pizzaObject = {
        pizza:[
            size= [
                'Small',
                'Medium',
                'Large'],
            price,                  //price depends on pizza size selection
            toppings = [
                 'Tomato',
                 'Onions',
                 'Peppers',
                 'Double Cheese',
                 'Pepperoni',
                 'Mushrooms']]}     //comes from radio buttons and check boxes selection, modify 
       
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pizza Order Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="./test.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <img src="" width="600" height="277" alt="Pizza Logo" />
        <h1>Pizza Order Form</h1>
    </header>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm();" target="_blank">
        <!-- http://lavalamp.dyndns.org/~mult114/pizzaorder_olympic.php -->
        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="difficulty" value="1" /> -->
        <fieldset id="contactinfo">
            <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Contact Information</strong></legend>

            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="Name"><br>
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="address" name="Address"><br>
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input type="tel" id="phone" name="Phone"><br>

        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="order-form">
            <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Order</strong></legend>
            <fieldset id="pizza-size">
                <legend>Pizza Size</legend>
                <input type="radio" id="small" name="Size" value="10" onclick="calculateSize(this);">
                <label for="small">Small</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="medium" name="Size" value="12" onclick="calculateSize(this);">
                <label for="medium">Medium</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="large" name="Size" value="14" onclick="calculateSize(this);">
                <label for="large">Large</label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="toppings">
                <legend>Topping(s)</legend>
                <input type="checkbox" id="tomato" name="tomato" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                <label for="tomato">Tomato</label><br>

                <input type="checkbox" id="onions" name="onions" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                <label for="onions">Onions</label><br>

                <input type="checkbox" id="peppers" name="peppers" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                <label for="peppers">Peppers</label><br>

                <input type="checkbox" id="doublecheese" name="DoubleCheese" value="yes"
                    onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                <label for="doublecheese">Double Cheese</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="pepperoni" name="Pepperoni" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                <label for="pepperoni">Pepperoni</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="mushrooms" name="Mushroom" value="yes" onclick="toppingOptionPrice(this);">
                <label for="mushrooms">Mushrooms</label><br>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="instructions">
                <legend>Special Instructions</legend>
                <textarea id="textarea" name="instructions" rows="5" cols="50"
                    placeholder="Enter your message here!(special requests, delivery details, etc.)"></textarea>
            </fieldset>
        </fieldset>

        <div id="my-pizza">
            <p>Here will be my pizza details</p>
            <p>pizza1</p>
            
        </div>
        <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
        <select name="quantity" id="quantity">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
        </select>


        <p><button id="addPizza" onclick="">Add Pizza</button></p>

        <fieldset id="orderPrice">
            <div id="my-order">
                <p>Here will be my order details</p>
                <p>pizza1</p>
                <p>pizza2</p>
                <p>pizza3</p>
            </div>
            <legend style="font-size: larger;"><strong>Order Total</strong></legend>

            <label for="subtotal">SubTotal $:</label>
            <input type="text" id="subtotal" name="SubTotal" readonly><br>

            <label for="tax">Tax 10% $:</label>
            <input type="text" id="tax" name="tax" readonly><br>

            <label for="total">Total $:</label>
            <input type="text" id="total" name="Total_tb" readonly><br>
        </fieldset>
        <p><button id="orderPizza" onclick="">Order Pizza</button></p>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I also made some sketches of the routine:

```js
'use strict'
// Order object, which contains a Customer object, an array of Pizza objects, and a nested array of toppings for each pizza.
function Order( toppings,address, phone,fullName,size,price )  {
       
    this.customer = new Customer(fullName, address, phone ),
    this.pizza = new Pizza(size, toppings, price)
    
    
}
function createOrder(){};

function Customer(fullName, address, phone){
    this.fullName = fullName,
    this.address = address,
    this.phone = phone,
    this.createCustomer = function(){
        fullName = document.getElementById("name");
        address = document.getElementById("address");
        phone = document.getElementById("phone");
    }
};

function Pizza(toppings,size, price){
    this.toppings = toppings;
    this.size = size;
    this.phone = price;
    pizza = [size,toppings, price];
    toppings = [""];
    this.createPizza = function (){
        
    };
};

function displayOrder(){
    let myOrder = new Order;
};
```

I would greatly appreciate it if somebody could give me some advice on how to build the algorithm for this problem **in vanilla HTML**. Would be great to have some pseudocode. I wrote seme just to  show how I break down this routine.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("checkbox, radio").addEventListener('change',  displayPizza)

function createOrder(){
    new Customer() //get values from input fields
    new Pizza( )//buld a pizza instance from current selection
    addPizza();  //if !validateInput make "Add Pizza" disabled
}
function CustomerConstructor(address, phone,fullName){}
function addPizza(){}   // add pizza to the order
function PizzaConstructor(){}   //  pizza constructor
function validateInput(checkboxes,radiobuttons,inputfields)//check if the inputs are valid and selected
function displayPizza()  //show pizza details in <div id="my-pizza">, update on every change of selection
```

Comment: All these `'pizza[1]'` and `'pizza[2]'` are literals spelled out like that on the array def. ... `size= [` inside declaring a var as object breaks as syntax. Use `:` instead of `=`.

Comment: I don't see the most important of all functions, `validateForm` . That's called on submit, and that's where you have to create the instances of your order, pizza, customer ,etc... based on form inputs values.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How far are you into this class? `document.querySelectorAll("checkbox, radio")` No. Try `('[type="checkbox"], [type="radio"]')` Note the alternating quotes (single, double...double, single)